# How do I create a pull request from an origin repository to a forked repostiory?

Tags: git, github

I'm the maintainer for a code base that has been forked off to an official project in GitHub. Recently I made a minor change and I want to submit a pull request to the official project. If my repository is `prime` and the official project is `official` then how I do I create a pull request from `prime` to `official`?

On GitHub it looks like by default it wants to go from `official` to `prime`.

Google Search: downstream pull request

Answer (score 0):

Using the github site, the repo on the left is the destination, and on the right the source.

[image: github pull request]

In this case, I am proposing pulling changes from `console-debug` in to `master`. The wording and layout isn't super clear though, I always used to question the directionality every time I made a new PR.

Once you've created the PR though it becomes a lot more clear

[image: created pr]

Comment: -1 I'm already aware of how to do this. This is the merge from `official` to `prime` that I mentioned. The problem I have is that I want to go from `prime` to `origin` (effectively a downstream pull request) for which the UI seems to fall over.

Comment: Harsh. You make no mention of `origin` in your original question, just `prime` to `official` which I answered.

Comment: My apologizes if it is harsh, but I literally say in my question "I'm the maintainer for a code base that has been forked off to an official project in GitHub."